# React Native error 'Unable to resolve module `react-native` '

Tags: android, react-native

I am attempting to learn `React Native` so I went ahead and followed all the steps in the [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) guide at the official documentation site. I have some experience with `React` so i wanted to expand on it.

I did wade in around 6 months ago for a simple 'hello world' app and everything worked fine for me on both the Android emulator and the IoS simulator. Did test on my device as well and had no issues. Since i got busy with other work i did not get back to it until now.

The error i get when i attempt the `react-native run-android` command:

```
    Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native` from `/Users/arunmenon/Sites/reactnative/website/index.js`: Module `react-native` does not exist in the Haste module map or in these directories:
  /Users/arunmenon/Sites/reactnative/website/node_modules

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/arunmenon/Sites/reactnative/website/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:161:1460)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/arunmenon/Sites/reactnative/website/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:91:16)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/arunmenon/Sites/reactnative/website/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:272:4579)
    at dependencies.map.relativePath (/Users/arunmenon/Sites/reactnative/website/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:376:19)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/arunmenon/Sites/reactnative/website/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:374:16)
    at /Users/arunmenon/Sites/reactnative/website/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:212:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/arunmenon/Sites/reactnative/website/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:313)
    at /Users/arunmenon/Sites/reactnative/website/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:473
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

I tried all the suggested steps but the issue still persists. The error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native` from `/Users/arunmenon/Sites/reactnative/website/index.js`: 
Module `react-native` does not exist in the Haste module map or in these directories:
  /Users/arunmenon/Sites/reactnative/website/node_modules
```

suggests that it looks like somehow there is some issue with picking up the path from `node_modules`. The first line in index.js is `import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';` and thats where the error is thrown.

The paths mentioned are valid and i do have react-native installed in the node_modules directory in the path.

I am developing on a Mac and the targeted device currently is Android. I am going the `react-native` CLI command route and not the `create-react-native-app` route.

I have Android Studio 3.1.3 (updated last night), Node 8.11.2, NPM 6.1.0,  Watchman 4.9.0 (installed via Homebrew), Java JDK 1.8.0_144.

I followed the getting started guid to a T. Since i got t working earlier - around 6 months ago - i wonder why i get this now. I have the same Android Studio version as then(i updated Android Studio yesterday to rule out issues with having an older version. I get the same error with the new version as well)  The difference between then and now:

- React-native library version has obviously been bumped up from then
- Java version, i recently updated it to the latest
- Node and NPM versions are newer
- Watchman also i think since Homebrew did update it

Everything else is the same. I tried a couple of fresh install as well - starting over from the beginning i.e but it didnt work.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "23.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please remove all react-native specific folders from "%appdata%\Temp" and then try below commands:

cd android
gradlew clean
cd.. and remove the node_modules folder
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npm start -- --reset-cache
react-native run-android

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The equivalent to a temp folder in Mac is `Library/cache` and the `$TMPDIR` as mentioned here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/131080. The first location had no react-native related directories but i found a few react references in `yarn` and `typescript` directories. I removed these directories. In the `$TMPDIR` structure there are no direct react-native references. I did find a `hatsmap` reference and a `metro` directory which i have removed. I am not sure which android directory you mean in `cd android`. Is it the sdk directory?

Comment: I also don't have the `gradlew` command available, at least when using via the terminal/prompt. I get `-bash: gradlew: command not found`. Should all this be done within Android Studio? I don't use Android Studio for development. I use Visual Studio Code alongwith either its inbuilt terminal or the globally available terminal for node/npm commands

Comment: All these commands are windows specific. There will be android folder in your project directory, go to that folder and open command prompt and run gradlew clean command there. That's it.

Comment: @arunmenon, yes you can use inbuilt or global terminal for running these commands. And for gradlew command, you have to be in android folder of your project, hope it will help you. Let me know if any issue

Comment: ok. `gradlew clean` inside the Android directory strangely still returns `command not found` despite having the unix-executible file `gradlew` as well as anotherfile named `gradlew.bat`. I am now attempting a total new setup of the app (running the init again) and will update here

Comment: Tried a lot of options, remove everything, add again etc. Nothing works. The only thing i havent tried is restoring the data to a backup taken 6 months ago, but thats an extreme step which i don't want to take. Incidently, its not an android-only issue. I get the very same error on IoS simulator. Here is a link with the exact error that i get: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11257 Since i need a mobile solution, im checking out Nativescripts to ensure a dev env. Hopefully the installation there will work out fine. The only issue is that i have go through large downloads again

Comment: Even if it does not work by today or tomorrow eod i will be accepting this answer as correct for other users who may come in here with similar issues. All my research show somewhat similar steps are required anyway.

Comment: Ive managed to get it going at last. While i cannot exactly pinpoint which of the several actions i took worked - i tried various options over the weekend - what needs to go to the checklist is to try a new fresh install in a different directory. Deleting the project directory and re-creating it with the same name didn't work. A new directory name would be required. One good thing thats come out is that i seem to be somewhat nativescript. dev ready as well. Thanks for the answer - a am accepting this as the correct answer since the answer has valid steps.

Answer (score 3):

The above didn't work for me on **Mac OSX**, but this one did: after `npm install`, run these:

```
# Clean cache
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*; watchman watch-del-all

# Start React-Native directly
react-native start --reset-cache

# Now run android/iOS in another tab
react-native run-android
```

Original post: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21490#issuecomment-427240356

Comment: ok. The project is shelved at the moment but this seems to be useful information. I guess ill refer back here in case i encounter the same issues in any upcoming React Native projects (i have one planned for the near future).

Comment: I am on a React Native project currently and the issue no longer appears in the  version that i am using  (`0.57.8`). So it is a combination of factors including having the latest version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was newly installed package. so try with uninstall the npm package which you newly installed. **npm uninstall  --save**

Comment: In my original issue it was a fresh install. No additional packages (besides the default packages installed by React Native) were added. But this solution is definitely valid in use-cases where there are existing packages and a new install triggered the issue. After all this while i definitely think my original issue was totally cache-related since even deleting and recreating the project with the same name had no effect.